# Jquery Include previous var in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, fullpage.js

I have a website where when you click on the menu on the index page, i want the user to be redirected to the page archive, with an anchor to that particular project. So when you click on project *355*, you get redirected to http://website.com/archive/#*355*

I used this html code :

```
<a  class="nav-menu <?php echo $post->ID; ?>" 
data-nav="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" 
href="/archive#<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" >
```

With this code, I added a data-nav attribute to extract the content (*355*) for each link of my menu, but I can't seem to get those values used in the script under.

```
$( "a.nav-menu" ).each(function(){
    var testdata = $(this).data("nav");
    console.log(testdata); 
});
```

In my console log, I get *321, 340, 355*, etc. so all of my projects "name"
And this is the script, I want to get the values of testdata in the anchor part

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
   scrollingSpeed: 1000,
   anchors: ['364', '355', '341', '334', '321', '315'],
   continuousVertical: true,
   fixedElements: '#button1Id, #button2Id'
 });
```

I have searched how to do this, but I didn't find how..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a test function for the items you specifed

the html items that I made test on them are

```
<a class="nav-menu 364" data-nav="364" href="/archive#364" >Test1</a>
<a class="nav-menu 355" data-nav="355" href="/archive#355" >Test2</a>
<a class="nav-menu 341" data-nav="341" href="/archive#341" >Test3</a>
<a class="nav-menu 334" data-nav="334" href="/archive#334" >Test4</a>
<a class="nav-menu 321" data-nav="321" href="/archive#321" >Test5</a>
<a class="nav-menu 315" data-nav="315" href="/archive#315" >Test6</a>
```

The Script for handling these Items is

```
var array = [];
$( "a.nav-menu" ).each(function(){
    var testdata = $(this).data("nav");
    array.push(testdata); 
});
console.log(array);
```

I have Initiated empty array before iteating through items then I can use it in fullpage funtion as follows

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
   scrollingSpeed: 1000,
   anchors: array,
   continuousVertical: true,
   fixedElements: '#button1Id, #button2Id'
 });
```

if you want items to be strings in array you should use

```
var testdata = $(this).data("nav").toString();
```

I hope my answer to be useful

Comment: Thank you so much! I never understood how array worked or how i could use them. This gives me much more understanding